# /proc/net/udp drops are negative values

Tags: unix, udp, proc

we have a Syslog-ng where it receives a massive number of UDP stream and I think that there are number of UDP packets are being dropped, can you please why I am getting negative values in /proc/net/udp [drops column]

#### netstat -su

```
    5322117448164 packets received
    874516751 packets to unknown port received.
    516387410736 packet receive errors
    351482789 receive buffer errors
    InCsumErrors: 897232
```

#### setting the max recieve size to 80MB

`sysctl net.core.rmem_max net.core.rmem_max = 83886080`

#### ss -ulnp shows Recv-Q around 80MB

`# ss -ulnp | grep syslog`

`UNCONN     83482560 0            *:9002                     *:*        (("syslogng",pid=15798,fd=6))`

#### /proc/net/udp

```
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops

51808: 00000000:232A 00000000:0000 07 00000000:04FFFEC0 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 3815546609 2 ffff88103f9fd500 -1437668106
```

can you please advise what does the negative values means in drops column

Comment: we have a bond active/standby on this system where syslog-ng receives the traffic if we change the bond type to type 6 - mode=6 (balance-alb). does it help to solve my issue, if i issue `ifstat bond1`  i cannot see any drops or errors on the interface level

Answer (score 0):

the drops are there due to the rmem_max configuration was not enough due to enormous traffic we are getting, but I the root cause of the issue is the misconfiguration of our syslog-ng 'unfortunately'.

we should fine-tune the application as well, not also the OS buffer.
the four parameters where you can start with are:

- log-fifo-size – The number of messages that the output queue can store..each destination has its own one of these. This is created for each destination we have.
- log-iw-size – The initial size of the input control window. Syslog-ng uses this as a control to see if the destination buffer has enough space before accepting more data.
- log-fetch-limit – The number of messages to pull at a time from each source.
- max-connections – The maximum number connections to accept